# making numerical categories of pandas data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I tried to look at some reference where I can make an extra column that is categorical based on another column. I tried the documentation already [pandas categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html), and stack overflow does not seem to have this, but I think it must be, but maybe I am using the wrong search tags?

for example

```
Size    Size_cat
10      0-50
50      0-50
150     50-500
450     50-500
5000    1000-9000
10000   >9000
notice that the size category 500-1000 is missing (but no number corresponds to that)
```

The problem lies here is that I create a pandas crosstable later like this:

```
summary_table = pd.crosstab(index[res_sum["Type"],res_sum["Size"]],columns=[res_sum["Found"]],margins=True)
summary_table = summary_table.div(summary_table["All"] / 100, axis=0)
```

After some editing of this table I get this kind of result:

```
Found                 Exact        Near          No
Type        Size                                   
DEL         50        80         20            0
            100       60         40            0
            500       80         20            0
            1000      60         40            0
            5000      40         60            0
            10000     20         80            0
DEL_Total             56.666667   43.333333    0
DUP         50         0           0         100
            100        0           0         100
            500        0         100           0
            1000       0         100           0
            5000       0         100           0
            10000     20          80           0
DUP_Total              3.333333   63.333333   33.333333
```

the problem is that now (Size) just puts the sizes here, and therefore this table can vary in size. If 5000-DEL is missing in the data, that column will also disappear and then DUP has 6 categories and DEL 5. Additionally if I add more sizes, this table will become very large. So I wanted to make categories of the sizes, but always retaining the same categories, even if some of them are empty.

I hope I am clear, because it is kinda hard to explain.
this is what I tried already:

```
highest_size = res['Size'].max()
categories = int(math.ceil(highest_size / 100.0) * 100.0)
categories = int(categories / 10)

labels = ["{0} - {1}".format(i, i + categories) for i in range(0, highest_size, categories)]
print(highest_size)
print(categories)
print(labels)
10000
1000
['0 - 1000', '1000 - 2000', '2000 - 3000', '3000 - 4000', '4000 - 5000', '5000 - 6000', '6000 - 7000', '7000 - 8000', '8000 - 9000', '9000 - 10000']
```

I get number categories, but of course now they depend on the highest number, and the categories change based on the data. additionally I still need to link them to the 'Size' column in pandas. This does not work.

```
df['group'] = pd.cut(df.value, range(0, highest_size), right=False, labels=labels)
```

If possible I would like to make my own categories, instead of using range to get the same steps, like I made in the first example above. (otherwise it takes way to long to get to 10000 with steps of 100, and taking steps of 1000 will lose a lot of data in the smaller regions)

Comment: cant your use lambda to create a Size_cat column on the initial dataframe and then crosstab?

Comment: Sounds easy :), how do you use lambda then?

Comment: I will do a quick mock up below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a mock up below, to help you get the logic. Basically, you bin the Score into custom groups, by using `cut` (or even  `lambda` or `map` ) and passing the value to the function `GroupMapping`. Let me know if it works.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({
        'Name':['Harry','Sally','Mary','John','Francis','Devon','James','Holly','Molly','Nancy','Ben'], 
        'Score': [1143,2040,2500,3300,3143,2330,2670,2140,2890,3493,1723]}
    )

def GroupMapping(dl):
    if int(dl) <= 1000: return '0-1000'
    elif 1000 < dl <= 2000: return '1000 - 2000'
    elif 2000 < dl <= 3000: return '2000 - 3000'
    elif 3000 < dl <= 4000: return '3000 - 4000'
    else: return 'None'

#df["Group"] = df['Score'].map(GroupMapping)
#df["Group"] = df['Score'].apply(lambda row: GroupMapping(row))
df['Group'] = pd.cut(df['Score'], [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000], labels=['0-1000', '1000 - 2000', '2000 - 3000','3000 - 4000' ])
df
```

Comment: I will give it a try, I let you know

Comment: Okay good. Another option is to use cut : df['bin'] = pd.cut(df['Score'], [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000], labels=['0-1000', '1000 - 2000', '2000 - 3000','3000 - 4000' ])

Comment: It sorta works, but not quite yet. I get the category "group" , but only the category 0-1000 is correctly made, and all the others are NaN. I tried to "fix" your code by putting `int(d1)` everywhere (instead of just the first if) and on both sides `<=`, but that also gives me that sizes 50, 100 and 500 are corretly labeled as 1-1000 and the rest is NaN.

I will try the other option as well

Comment: The second option with pd.cut works like a charm. I will try to implement that code into my own code tomorrow :), but I still might have the problem that some categories now dont exist, if the number doesn't exist in any category ...

Comment: super. please see if you can mark it as the answer. thank you

Comment: I marked your answer, but after writing the script, I found out that only the solution in the comment actually worked. maybe you could update your answer, so that there will be no confusion for future visitors? (otherwise I can post my own answer with my final code, but that feels like stealing your answer)

Comment: Really good feedback @Fini. I have updated the answer to reflect that method.